# how to store and read 4d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am new to Python. I am trying to store a 4d numpy array in a file (done it) and read the values of this file (there's the problem). The code is:

```
import numpy as np

Lx=6;Ly=6,Lz=2 
mat=np.zeros((Lx,Ly,Lz,3),dtype=np.float)

mat=np.random.rand(Lx,Ly,Lz,3)

outfile=open("config.txt","w")


for i in range(0,Lx):
    for j in range(0,Ly):
        for k in range(0,Lz):
           print(mat[i,j,k,0], mat[i,j,k,1], mat[i,j,k,2],file=outfile)

outfile.close() 


mnew=np.zeros((Lx,Ly,Lz,3),dtype=np.float)

infile=open("config.txt","r")

for i in range(0,Lx):
    for j in range(0,Ly):
        for k in range(0,Lz):
            infile.read(mnew[i,j,k,0], mnew[i,j,k,1], mnew[i,j,k,2])
```

I get the error:

> infile.read(mnew[i,j,k,0], mnew[i,j,k,1], mnew[i,j,k,2]) TypeError:
>   read() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)

but I don't know how to fix it

Thanks,
M

Comment: Take a look at python's `read` function [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Comment: I don't see how this helps

Comment: Python's `read` function of files reads from files, but it does not read directly into variables. If you insist on using read like such without using proper `numpy` functions for loading and saving files, what I think you want is to read the lines using `readlines` and insert into variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution to save and read numpy arrays is to just use numpy functions [`np.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`np.load`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

```py
import numpy as np
example = np.random.rand(6, 6, 2, 3)

#save
example.save('example.npy')

#read back
example_copy = np.load('example.npy')
```

Comment: this is a 4d matrix, not an array

Comment: @mgeo in `numpy` terms `array` means `ndarray`, which can have arbitrary dimension.   `mat` and `mnew` are already `ndarray`s

Comment: thanks, I tried:    
    with open('newstore','w') as ff: 
        np.save(ff,mat)
     ff.closed
     mnew=np.load(ff)              
but it didn't work

Comment: You can even skip the `open` with these functions. I added a minimal example.